# Is this a valid use case for SqlCLR? Adapting stored procedure results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I have already implemented the CLR stored procedure that I describe below and it works well enough. But I'm not sure if I really need CLR to accomplish this, or if a middle tier solution would have been just as performant and maintainable.

In the existing code base, this company has accrued 500+ search stored procedures over the years. Now they want me to write an aggregation engine that works for all of these stored procedures. Every search stored procedure in their system follows a similar format so I know how to programatically call them with the correct parameters etc.

I don't want to modify each search stored procedure in any way. What I'd prefer to do is first insert the results of the stored procedure into a temp table. Then I can run my aggregation engine by querying the temp table.

The trouble is, in SQL Server you can't insert the results of the stored procedure unless you know the EXACT schema of the stored procedure results. But that isn't really possible because the stored procedures can return different result schema depending on the parameters.

So in order to guarantee that the stored procedure would return the EXACT schema I was expecting, I created an "SP_Wrapper" CLR stored procedure. Within this wrapper I call a stored procedure and "adapt" each record to my expected schema.  I then return the adapted result set.

Then I can insert into my temp table knowing that the schema was correct.

Now, lets say I adapted the results on the middle tier. I would have had to first return the result to the middle tier. Iterate through them, adapt each record, then insert separately or bulk copy.

It seemed like the correct choice but now I have to deploy this CLR stored procedure. Am I really gaining much here?

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
{
        conn.Open();

        //load result table schema
        resultColumns = SqlSchema.getTempTableMeta(conn, resultTableName);

        //load parameter table schema - may not exist
        var hasParams = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(paramTableName);
        parameters = SqlSchema.getTempTableMeta(conn, paramTableName);

        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        ///Load Parameter Values
        if (hasParams)
        {
            command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = $@"if( object_id('tempdb..{paramTableName}') is not null) select top 1 * from {paramTableName};";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            using (reader)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    foreach (var p in parameters)
                    {
                        var val = reader[p.Name];

                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val?.ToString()))
                            parameter_values[p.Name] = val;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(resultColumns.ToArray());

        //////mark the beginning of the result set
        SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(record);

        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = spName;

        foreach (var p in parameters)
        {
            if (parameter_values.ContainsKey(p.Name))
                command.Parameters.Add(
                    new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = p.Name,
                        SqlDbType = p.SqlDbType,
                        Value = parameter_values[p.Name]
                    }
                );
        }

        var cmdReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        using (cmdReader)
        {
            while (cmdReader.Read())
            {
                int sequence = 0;
                foreach (var resultColumn in resultColumns)
                {
                    var resultColumnValue = cmdReader[resultColumn.Name];

                    var t = resultColumn.SqlDbType;

                    resultColumnValue = SqlSchema.Convert(resultColumnValue, SqlSchema.sqlTypeMap[t]);

                    record.SetValue(sequence, resultColumnValue);
                    sequence++;
                }
                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
            }
        }

        // Mark the end of the result-set.
        SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can use openrowset.  The trouble is I'm deploying this to another environment and that requires "Ad Hoc Distributed Queries" and query string information etc.

Comment: Hey there. I am just curious as to what approach you finally settled on, and why. Do you mind sharing? If yes, please leave a comment on my answer with that info. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I am moving toward deploying my CLR solution.  I tested a couple alternate approaches, the bulk copy from the middle tier, and the clr implementation performed far better.  I didn't want to use CLR because I have to create a deployment script that will run as part of the products dbms update process.  But I will follow your guide and let you know how it turns out.  Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it depends on:

1. What are doing with the data returned from the stored procedures?

   The code posted in the question is missing some pieces, so it is not entirely clear if you are grabbing all, or just some, of the returned columns. One benefit of your current approach is that you have the ability to ignore columns you aren't interested in when dumping the results into the temp table(s). Generating T-SQL code to do the `INSERT...EXEC` in pure T-SQL won't allow you to filter out entire columns; you have to insert all columns into the destination table whether you want to or not.
2. Are there any other potential uses for this interface to those search procs?

   One benefit of the SQLCLR approach is that it is more generally available to use. If this functionality is housed within app code, then it is only app code that can ever use it. You won't be able to use it in a SQL Agent Job (without calling app code, which might require writing a console app pointing to the same library, or making the library a PowerShell module). You won't be able to use it in a proc that is the source for an automated report sent via Database Mail. You won't be able to easily extended its use into other areas that have yet to be requested. Just something to consider if any of those use cases seems possible.
3. I am not 100% sure about this, but your current approach *might* allow you to side-step the restriction on doing `INSERT...EXEC` if the proc you are executing (or one of its sub-processes, if there are any), has an `INSERT...EXEC`.

   (I don't have time to test this right now, but when I do, if I find that it doesn't side-step the restriction, I will remove this point.)

While SQLCLR isn't as straight-forward as T-SQL from a deployment / CI perspective, it also isn't impossible. Sure, Visual Studio / SSDT really doesn't make it easy to automate deployments when needing to handle security properly (i.e. using signature-based Logins instead of enabling `TRUSTWORTHY`), and this is a necessity if using SQL Server 2017 or newer. To help with this, I demonstrate two similar approaches that work with Visual Studio / SSDT or independently, discussed in the following two blog posts of mine:

1. [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/) — more steps than Part 3, Solution 2 (below), but a good fit for existing projects as it requires almost no changes to the existing solution or even deployment process (and in fact, this is effectively the route that I went for my [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_52695039) project as all it did was add 3 simple steps to the beginning of the installation script). This solution uses an Asymmetric Key for the signature.
2. [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 3: “CLR strict security” – Solution 2](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/). This solution uses a Certificate for the signature.

The goal of both of those solutions is not only to work with Visual Studio / SSDT, but also to produce a self-contained T-SQL script. The T-SQL script has no external references: not to any DLL files, nor to any .snk / .cer / .pfx files. This makes the script completely portable, hence much easier to work into any Continuous Integration setup :-).

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://SQLCLR.org/)

Answer (score 3):

In principle this solution makes sense. You are using SQL CLR as an adapter to convert to a known schema. The code that you wrote looks efficient as well.

The downside is that SQL CLR code is harder to write, harder to test and harder to deploy than normal code.

Whether this tradeoff is right for you or not depends on your performance needs and needs for developer productivity. Does this data copying really consume that much time that it's worth it to touch SQL CLR?! It might or it might not.

A different and faster solution would be to generate SQL code for each procedure that you must call. Don't hand write it. Instead make a tool determine the exact schema of that procedure and output perfect T-SQL that directly pipes the data in the right format into the right destination.

This tool could indeed be a SQL CLR procedure that generates the code and then executes it. Or, it could be a C# based code generator.